# Powering a Servo: Do I need a separate power source?

Tags: power-supply, power, motor, robotics, servo

I have a project that utilizes two strong digital, coreless servo motors.  Whenever I use DC motors, I usually need to have separate power sources for both the microcontroller and the motors (due to noise and such).  I don't have as much experience with servos, is this still the case?  I'd really like to get away with using just one battery, are there any precautions I can take for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever possibe use a seperate power supply.
(We do in a 4kg robot)

Use a proper noise filter if you must share a power source. An isolated DC-DC converter to supply the electronics is very effective (active filter).

Opto-isolate from the MCU to servo power amplifier.

It's the rule in industrial, where reliability matters.

Never share grounds.

Answer (score 1):

I've used several servo's in combination with a 30W motor on a college project and never had a problem with noise. The servo's took about 1 Amp at 5V when they can't move (but are trying to). Please take note that you should never exceed their voltage specification for too long, neither block them, as they seem to burn out quite quickly (we ran one at 6.5V for 1 hour while it was rated at 6V - it burned a nice hole in it).

You could try decoupling the engine from the normal supply by using an inductor and some decoupling capacitors. We made some DIY coils: we wrapped some copper wire around some plastic rings and installed them at both motor terminals (the other side of the inductors go to VCC and GND of power pack). In addition we used 10nF and 33nF capacitors at the terminals (10nF between, 33nF to the motor casing I believe). Note that we used high voltages ones because of possible surge voltages.

I heard horror stories of 'dancing servos' from other teams when they fired up their motor. I don't think a servo is that harmful because it uses a rather small motor. If you're using a chunky one, I recommended using decoupling with an inductor.